# Laravel set cookie in API not set

Tags: php, laravel

I using laravel 5 as Rest API, and I want to set a cookie in controller:

```
return response()->json(['success' => $data], $this-> successStatus)->cookie('name', 'myvalue');
```

this return with response cookie successfully, but can not access in front, I also used:

```
Cookie::queue($name, $value);
```

Or

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookieName', 'value'));
```

Or all way in google, stackoverflow, but none of these set cookie in browser, I need to set http only cookie in browser via laravel controller. how can i do this?

I also used php cookie, no success

Answer (score 3):

Normally we cannot set cookies in API route due to EncryptCookies and AddQueuedCookiesToResponse not being added by default. So we have to add those classes in the kernel with API middleware.

```
   'api' => [
   //my change
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
   \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
   //end of my change

    \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
     'throttle:api',
     \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
 ],
```

Then we can set and get a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies will be set on `web` middleware group only not `api`. According to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-groups),  Laravel comes with `web` and `api` middleware groups that contain common middleware you may want to apply to your web UI and API routes:

```php
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        //...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
];
```

As you can see, `EncryptCookies` and `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` middlewares are applied to `web` group only but not `api`.

```php
// This works and sets encrypted cookie on response.
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    return response()
        ->cookie('name', 'value');
});

// This won't set cookie on response.
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {
    return response()
        ->cookie('name', 'value');
});
```

Comment: First part is clear, but I don't understand last part, so how can I set cookie in controller?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse(['success' => $data], $this->successStatus);
$response->withCookie(cookie($cookieName, $cookieVal, 45000));
return $response;
```

[Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html)

Comment: Your code and other code that I mentioned in my question work fine just only with response, this mean: for example I go to network tab in google chrome, when see api request, cookie is set with response, but not global, when I go to application , cookies, it not set here, and I can not access it in other page, for example in front page.